# How did the slave chance upon the artifact?

Tags: internal-consistency

The slaves are mostly in their master's houses. They do most of the work of the world, including working in factories, cleaning the world, maintaining their master's houses(except cooking), pleasuring, etc. But they do all of this work either in closed rooms or in chains.

The artifact is in the king's artifact room, which is accessible only by the royal family. The slave which chances upon the artifact works in the king's house. So, how does he enter the artifact room?

Note- A theory I created was that the slave would be a pleasure slave to the king's young daughter(different kind of society), he would have a craving to see artifacts and she would let him enter the artifact room on his request. But this would not be fit for a young adult book.
So, any other ideas?

Comment: You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world.

Comment: On which stack exchange site should I post it?

Comment: I don't know if writers.stackexchange.com would accept this. The "problem" with Stack Exchange is that it aims to be a knowledge base. Thus, pooling for ideas where every answer may be equally good and only way to judge them is if you like it, wouldn't really be welcome on any site.

Comment: So, how should I edit my question so that it becomes suitable for stack exchange?

Comment: Just an observation: In any historically known society which had a large-ish number of slaves the _vast_ majority of the slaves were _not_ kept in chains; in fact, the slaves went about their work just about as freely as free people. In ancient Athens, the _police_ were slaves. Some slaves were _soldiers_ -- see the [Mamluks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamluk) of the Ottoman Empire. When thinking about a slave-holding society remember that the Southern states of the U.S. in the 19th century were an anomaly, out of sync with the times, not at all typical of a society which had slavery.

Comment: In order to make a question acceptable, you need to follow the [scope of the site](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and phrase it in such way that it is possible to answer based on knowledge and not just opinion. Often, but not always, is a good way to do so by setting up restrictions for your scenario. Unfortunately I can't think of any concrete examples of such restrictions for your particular question; I would say that you need to give a reason for him to enter, but since that's what you are requesting, you might need to change your premise (see @AlexP's comment).

Comment: Rough suggestion for changing from plot-oriented to world-building oriented:

Comment: try usual friendship instead of sex, if you are looking for alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Slaves go everywhere

In a slavery society, it would be reasonable to expect that in any rich household, all menial tasks related to household maintenance would be done by slaves. "The slaves are mostly in their master's houses" implies household slavery as opposed to e.g. industrial, mining or plantation labor, so slaves would actually be everywhere around the house, not closed rooms - although it may be "good style" to ensure that they always are out of sight when not required or desired, just like good non-slave servants in rich settings.

Who cleans the room with the artifact? Slaves do. Who else?

Who carries furniture and other heavy objects in/out/around the room? Slaves do. If you need a gold statue moved, you're not going to do it yourself, it requires multiple strong slaves.

Who built the room? Chances are, that some of the low-skilled labor in constructing the room and especially 'refreshing' its interior was done by slaves; and quite possibly more than that - in the ancient world it was also reasonable to keep exceptionally skilled craftsmen and artists as slaves; wars were a common source of slaves so it would be quite feasible for *the best* masters of a conquered city (possibly on the other side of the world and conquered by someone else) to be taken/sold to some king to work on his projects as slaves.

Answer (score 1):

> The artifact is in the king's artifact room, which is accessible only by the royal family. The slave which chances upon the artifact works in the king's house. So, how does he enter the artifact room?

Has he got permission? Has he got motivation?

- Permission, but no motivation: he's there basically against his will. Maybe that artifact, or some other artifact in the same room, requires periodically a disposable human - to be disposed of afterwards to prevent him from talking, or suffering damage in whatever operation is required (e.g. taking the Wizard's Highly Radioactive Helmet from its leaden casket for cleaning), or being consumed by the operation itself (e.g. his lifeforce will fuel the Kingdom Integrity Spell).
- Permission and motivation: he's commanded to retrieve something there by a lazy prince(ss), or he's curious as in your own scenario.
- Motivation, but no permission: he enters by burglary. Or maybe he attempts to rescue someone he heard crying in the room (such initiative is unlikely in a slave). His motives may range from curiosity to a plot and treason most foul, to attempting to seize an(other) artifact to restore a love one's health or because forced to through blackmail.
- Neither motivation nor permission: he enters unwittingly and by chance (quake ruining the room's door, magical attack against the castle, that artifact or some other teleporting him for reasons unknown).